# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: E:\Codes\Php\Laravel\appoint_now-master\resources\views\staff\scheduler\index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

**I am new in laravel. I need help**

when I try to send data to index page through compact() method, then error is showing showing

**Error**

ErrorException
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: E:\Codes\Php\Laravel\appoint_now-master\resources\views\staff\scheduler\index.blade.php)

index.blade.php

```
 </thead>
                <tbody>
               @foreach($schedules as $s)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $s->name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $s->created_at }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="btn-group btn-block">
                                <a href="{{ route('staff.scheduler.edit', $s->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary" title="@lang('messages.edit')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> @lang('messages.edit')
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

*controller*

```
public function index()
{
    $user = auth()->guard(GuardType::STAFF)->user();
    $schedules=StaffSchedules::where('staff_id','=',$user->id)->first();
    //dd($schedules);

    return view('staff.scheduler.index',compact('schedules'));
}
```

*Routes*

```
 Route::prefix('businessStaffMember')->name('businessStaffMember.')->middleware([GuardType::BUSINESS])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', [BusinessBusinessStaffMemberController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    Route::get('/create', [BusinessBusinessStaffMemberController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
    Route::get('/{businessStaffMember}/edit', [BusinessBusinessStaffMemberController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');
    Route::post('/', [BusinessBusinessStaffMemberController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
    Route::patch('/{businessStaffMember}', [BusinessBusinessStaffMemberController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
});
```

Comment: `StaffSchedules::where('staff_id','=',$user->id)->first();` You're getting the `->first()` schedule. But it looks like you want a collection of schedules. You can replace `->first()` by `->get()`

Comment: Ok.it worked. thanks..

Comment: if any answer is helpful mark it as the best answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here:

```
$schedules=StaffSchedules::where('staff_id','=',$user->id)->first();
```

**first() returns object**

**while @foreach needs array!!**

**note:** if you want to render objects in foreach you should implement iterator interface just like our friend in commnets below has told

change it to below code and try again:

```
$schedules=StaffSchedules::where('staff_id','=',$user->id)->get();
```

Comment: Actually, objects can also be used in `foreach` statements if they've implemented `Iterator` interface. More info is here [https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

Comment: didnt know that thanks. but in this case i dont think he implemented that right? and problem is rendering object in foreach

Comment: Yes, your answer is helpful. I just wanted to mention that *while @foreach needs array!!* is not 100% true.

Comment: yes i will edit my answer now.. really thank you